# Two LINQ statements to one awaitable LINQ database query (Optimize)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Hey everyone i have a working LINQ query but i was wondering if it could be optimized even more..

this is what i'm doing right now:

```
var selectionsAnimals = await this.context.SelectionAnimals
                                        .GroupBy(a => a.AnimalId)
                                        .ToListAsync();

var animalsSelections = selectionsAnimals
                         .Select(a => new AnimalsSelection
                                 {
                                     AnimalId = a.First().AnimalId,
                                     SelectionIds = a.Select(b => b.SelectionId)
                                                   .OrderBy(b => b)
                                                   .ToList()
                                 })
                         .ToList();
```

**I was wondering if these two LINQ statements could be merged and as one awaitable LINQ query to the database?**

This is the Database entity:

```
public class SelectionAnimals
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public int SelectionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model:

```
public class AnimalsSelection
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public IList<int> SelectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

in the end i'm mapping animalsSelection to a `IEnumerable<AnimalsSelection>` (the model)

Comment: How many `SelectionAnimals` are you expecting to have in DB?

Comment: @Euphoric around a few thousand to a few million maybe. Right now there are 34 SelectionAnimals as we're not live yet

Comment: @MichaelCoxon The example `selectionsAnimals` variable uses that override

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Michael Coxon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761993/two-linq-statements-to-one-awaitable-linq-database-query-optimize/40762392#40762392) is right in general, but EF Core currently is quite unstable in even basic query construct processing.

So (sadly) the most important question is what EF Core version are you using. It's really a trial and error process. For instance, in EF Core 1.1.0 (release), Michael's construct does not work but the following equivalent does:

```
var animalsSelections = await db.SelectionAnimals
    .GroupBy(a => a.AnimalId)
    .Select(g => new AnimalsSelection
    {
        AnimalId = g.Key,
        SelectionIds = g.OrderBy(a => a.SelectionId)
                        .Select(a => a.SelectionId)
                        .ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test on 1.0.0 here, let me know if the above works.

Comment: Ahh.. so is it the reversed order of the `OrderBy` and `Select` since it is on the real object not a bunch of `int`'s?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I have no idea why. Both are equivalent and should translate to one and the same. Bugs, bugs ...

Comment: @Baklap4 since you care about performance, and there might be millions of rows - don't forget to check what sql query is generated by this LINQ query, it might be not what you would expect.

Comment: @Evk EF Core has mixed execution concept. You'll probably be surprised that all the solutions (OP, mine, yours, Michael's) generate one and the same SQL: `SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AnimalId], [a].[CreatedAt], [a].[SelectionId], [a].[UpdatedAt]
FROM [SelectionAnimals] AS [a]
ORDER BY [a].[AnimalId]`

Comment: No I'm not surprised, because that's exactly why I warn @Baklap4 to take care about which query is generated. He might be surprised that there is no GROUP BY statement in that query at all for example. Many people are sure that EF LINQ query always executes entirely by database and there are no internal in-memory operations by EF itself (what you call mixed execution I suppose) at all. In this case, perfomance of this query when number of SelectionAnimals will go from 34 to millions (in production) might be very surprising (and you can do better with raw sql query of course).

Comment: @Evk EF Core Roadmap says they are working on. So some day it would be as the people expect. Until then, the documentation has a section called *is it right for you* :)

Comment: I'm not going to touch it with a ten meter pole at the current state :) But thing is - EF 6 behaves in a similar way on some complex queries. For similar query it will generate of course not THAT bad sql query, but still surprising (no group by also for example). And maybe it cannot generate better even (as stated in answer by Euphoric).

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` returns an `IQueryable` so I am pretty sure there is nothing stopping you from doing...

```
var animalsSelections = await this.context.SelectionAnimals
                        .GroupBy(a => a.AnimalId)
                        .Select(a => new AnimalsSelection
                        {
                            AnimalId = a.First().AnimalId,
                            SelectionIds = a.Select(b => b.SelectionId)
                                            .OrderBy(b => b)
                                            .ToList()
                        })    
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i've tried. Yet this gives me an Error: viewable at this link: http://pastebin.com/0aQGqNcB I think this is due to the fact of the list within a list (by creating a new object of AnimalsSelection (the model)) since this list is not created async.

Comment: ok - well change your model to be `public IEnumerable<int> SelectionIds { get; set; }` and get rid of the `ToList` in the `Select`

Comment: I've changed the model and got rid of the `ToList` in the `Select` Yet still the same. As SelectionId's is now a IEnumerable<int> it can't still be used for parameter of type: `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Int32]`

Comment: @MichaelCoxon *there is nothing stopping you from doing* True in general, but there is something called EF Core where (currently) general rules do not apply :(

Comment: @IvanStoev So this is an EFCore thing? Because I swear I have done this in EF6 before... I could be mistaken..

Comment: Yeah, EF Core currently is a big disappointment (and EF6 regression).

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't faster way than getting all `AnimalId` and `SelectionId` and then grouping them on the client. It could be slightly improved by ordering by `AnimalId` and then using custom group-by that assumes the items are sorted by key. This might actually be required if you are also ordering the `SelectionIds`.

But as you say in your comment, you are going to have millions of records, which means that the query will return all of them.

Another option is to concatenate the `SelectionIds` into [single comma-separated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string), but that is outside of power of LINQ, so you have to go through raw SQL.